# Check if $(S,+)$ is a group where $S=\{\frac{4n+1}{4m+1}:m,n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification

Addition is closed and associative in $S$.There is no neutral element for addition in $S$ because if $e=0\Rightarrow n=\frac{-1}{4} \in \mathbb{Q}$ and also there is no inverse. $(S,+)$ is a semigroup.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's even closed.

If we take the element $\frac{1}{5}$ and sum it with itself, then we get $\frac{2}{5}$, which isn't in the required form for any integers $n,m$.

You can see this by writing
$$\frac{2}{5}=\frac{4n+1}{4m+1}$$
$$8m+2=20n+5$$

and noting that the left hand side is always even, whilst the right hand side is always odd.

Comment: Exactly: $S$ is definitely not closed under $+$ as you showed, hence $(S,+)$ is not a magma, hence it's not a group.